# Discord Python Bot Breaking My Commands When Using Background Task

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

I am working on a discord bot in python that send a scheduled message in a server at very specific times every day as well as other functionalities. After implementing the scheduled message, the bot commands no longer work - so the users can't use any of the commands but the scheduled message works.

I have the bot set up so it sends a message at 12:00,19:00,21:00,22:00,23:00 UTC. The only problem is now the commands such as ";help" do not work.

```
import discord
import datetime
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ';',help_command=None) #prefix

race_times_utc = [12,19,21,22,23]
time = datetime.datetime.now
    
async def timer():

  await client.wait_until_ready()

  msg_sent = False

  while not client.is_closed():
    if any(time().hour == race for race in race_times_utc) and time().minute == 0:
      if not msg_sent:
        channel = client.get_channel(838626115326636022)
        racer_role = get(channel.guild.roles, name = 'Racers')

        embed = discord.Embed(
          title = 'Race Time',
          description = 'Scheduled reminder for everyone that race starts soon.',
          colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )
    
        await channel.send(f'{racer_role.mention}',embed=embed)
        msg_sent = True
    else:
      msg_sent = False

  await asyncio.sleep(1)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=' ;help'))
    client.loop.create_task(timer())
    print('Bot is alive')

#Functions such as this no longer working
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
...
```

Comment: Are you aware that `asyncio.sleep` is **outside** the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) as it seems part of your code is blocking.

```py
import discord
import datetime
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ';',help_command=None) #prefix

race_times_utc = [12,19,21,22,23]
time = datetime.datetime.now

@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)  # replaces the sleep
async def timer():
    msg_sent = False
    if any(time().hour == race for race in race_times_utc) and time().minute == 0:
      if not msg_sent:
        channel = client.get_channel(838626115326636022)
        racer_role = get(channel.guild.roles, name = 'Racers')

        embed = discord.Embed(
          title = 'Race Time',
          description = 'Scheduled reminder for everyone that race starts soon.',
          colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )
    
        await channel.send(f'{racer_role.mention}',embed=embed)
        msg_sent = True
    else:
      msg_sent = False

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=' ;help'))
    print('Bot is alive')
    timer.start()
```

Comment: The code is not really blocking, he's simply not leaving the event loop free, he's keeping it busy all the time and the other coroutines cannot be scheduled